# Invalid Endpoint When Attempting to Create S3 via AWSCLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I am attempting to create an s3 bucket in aws via awscli but keep getting the error:

> Invalid endpoint: https://s3.[us-east-1].amazonaws.com

AFAIK, from all the reading and searching, I have configured everything correctly (note, that I wiped out the Access Keys below so as not to broadcast online my private info).

[image]

I haven't seen this in the research I've done, but it seems to add the `[]` around the region by default, which may be throwing it off. I don't know how to change that if that is the issue.

For example, in the error message it shows up, and if I re-run aws configure, it displays `Default region name [[us-east-1]]`.

I have also tried this, which fails, and makes no sense to me why not:

[image]

Anyone have any tips on what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just created a new S3 bucket using the aws cli using below command :-

`aws s3api create-bucket --bucket test-ami-test --region us-east-1`, here `test-ami-test` is my bucket name.

According to docs on AWS http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/create-bucket.html , below command is used to create a bucket :-

`aws s3api create-bucket --bucket my-bucket --region us-east-1`.

Also can you run `aws configure list` command and check the O/P matches the one specified in http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/configure/list.html.

Although I think your aws cli is configured properly, it's just you are not using correct command to create a bucket.

Comment: Thank you! This worked. I had code above from a lab I am doing on `ACloudGuru`. I know you may not know the answer to this, but is the code I had old way of doing it? Or perhaps since the author is on linux the commands are different than windows? Meaning, maybe `s3api` works on Windows and `s3` on linux?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman, I used above command on my mac and I don't think `s3api` is platform depend... as it worked on mac, it will definitely work on linux as well.

Comment: I am happy to be post a new question, but wanted to write this to you first, since maybe you have a quick solution. Now, I get same error when trying to update a lambda function. cmd line text is: `aws lambda update-function-code --zip-file=fileb://csv_parse.zip --function-name acgLambdaLab1`. According to aws docs this should work.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman, I hv not worked with aws lambda but I can try.. If you can explain what does your code do.. then I can try it on my aws setup.

Comment: Thank you, Amit. that line of code will update the script for a lambda function with a zip file (that has `.js` files in it) in the local directory. The link you provided me earlier has all the documentation if you look into the index and find `lambda` then `update-function-code`.